# Setgid bit - is it a security risk?

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, security, directory, file-sharing

After quite some research on this topic it is still not completely clear to me if it is unsafe to do -  I´m newbie!

1. If we only talk about setting the setgid bit, and only on a shared directory!
2. And if we make sure the owner of the shared directory is not root. (But one with root privileges).

How big of a security risk is this for the system?

Why would we do this? Because of convenience - else all the users should use chgrp all the time, when they create a file or a directory inside the shared directory, if the other groupmembers should be able to use the files.

Comment: It's not really clear, whats the question. But maybe you should have a look at package `acl` and read the manual of the included programs.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. I will edit the question so it becomes more clear. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setgid bit - is it a security risk?

ANY permissions more than needed is a security risk. Not all are exploitable remotely though and are considered a risk locally (so users not being admin being able to do something there are not meant to do).

> else all the users should use chgrp all the time, when they create a file or a directory inside the shared directory, if the other groupmembers should be able to use the files.

That is not needed,

Shared directories you want to share among different users you group by a group and no there is no need for normal users to ever need to use chgrp or chmod. That is an admin task. In the case of sharing you tell the software you use (for instance samba, or vsftp) to create new files with that group.

Generally there is no need to use setgid as you can set this in the configuration of the software used.

setgid means that newly created files get the same group as the directory, and newly created subdirectories get the set group id of the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks for a very well explained answer. I must look more into this. I am following the popular book : "The Linux Command Line" by W. E. S. jr.  It uses the setgid bit on shared directories on page 92.    Will you recommend to always use a software like samba or vsftp in combination with shared directories?  The book does not mention anything about it.

Comment: I just tested and there is no need just as you wrote. But there is one downside. The last person editing the file - lets say it is a text file - will become the owner of the file and group for file will also be the last editor of the file. If it does mean anything?

Comment: Just a small comment, if user X makes a subdirectory and the setgit bit is not set, user Y will not be able to write in this directory because it is owned and grouped to user X. So user X could use chgrp to make the subdirectory part of the shared group.

Comment: @mortenlund 1st comment: owner should not matter as long as the group is correct (and the group might need r, wr or rwx depending on the file). 2nd comment: "and grouped to user X" AND user Y... they are in the same group. Just make sure the group sets a dir as 770. (I assume your test created it as 750 (as that is likely the default) or lower).  The execute part on the group for the dir solves your issue ;)

Comment: Qoute:"there is no need for normal users to ever need to use chgrp or chmod. That is an admin task."        I then suppose the user will normally only use a GUI? Or is the terminal needed?

Comment: I ask (comment above) because if it is to be possible for the normal users to create files and directories in the terminal, their primary group must be the same as the shared Directory´s group, which is the group created by sudo and given to the users so they can use the shared directory.  If it is only supplemantary group, then they can use newgrp and temporary change primary group, create file or Directory and then change back again.